# Forward Slashes in Strings Aren't Allowing HTML To Work Properly For JLabels

Tags: java, html, swing, jframe, jlabel

I'm trying to create a JLabel with a mixed fraction. This is the code in HTML for the JLabel.

```
<html>70 <span class="f"><div class="n">3</div><div class="d">5</div></span></html>
```

This HTML code prints out the following, (sorry i cant post images)

[image]

Although you cannot put this code into a string because strings don't allow for the " character without a forward slash in front of them.

[image]

So this makes me change it with the forward slashes in front of the " characters like this.

[image]

But now, the HTML code is interpreted with the forward slashes, and so the output of the HTML code now looks like this.

[image]

Comment: *"strings don't allow for the " character without a forward slash in front of them"* Incorrect. Embedded `"` double-quote characters needs to be escaped with a ``\`` *backslash*, not a `/` forward slash.

Comment: Use this instead: `<html>7<sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>5</sub></html>`

Comment: That HTML will always show 3 numbers on 3 lines, since there is **no CSS** defining the classes `n` and `d`. See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1jdbo6cp/) for proof.